# Removing Empty List elements

Tags: python, regex, list

I have a list of source code that is getting looked through to find matching a string and returns all matches in a list. 
The issue is that I get an empty list element each time no match was found.

For example : ["matchone","",matchtwo"", .....]

The code looks like this:

```
    name_match = re.compile("\s\w+\(")
    match_list = []
    match_list_reformat = []

   for x in range(0,30):
       if name_match.findall(source_code[x]) != None:
        match_list.append(gc_name_match.findall(source_code[x]))
        format = "".join([c for c in match_list[x] if c is not '(']).replace("(", "")
        match_list_reformat.append(format)

return match_list_reformat
```

Using "if name_match.findall(source_code[x]) != None:" doesnt change the outcome.

On a side note. How can i go through all of the lines of the source code with this def? The range(0,30) is only a workaround.

Comment: An empty list will not compare equal to `None`. Just use `if name_match.findall(source_code[x])` to catch the empty list

Comment: also regexps are not exactly cheap so you may want to use an intermediate variable instead of doing the same call twice

Comment: maybe **if len(match_list_reformat) != 0 then return match_list_reformat** works

Comment: @markkeven Python objects have a truth value already, so the idiomatic way would be a plain and simple  `if match_list_reformat: ...`

Comment: "On a side note. How can i go through all of the lines of the source code with this def? The range(0,30) is only a workaround." => I think you should really take a couple hours doing the official Python tutorial - you obviously don't know the very basics of the language. Python's for loop is really a "foreach" loop, so you basically iterate over an iterable (list, string, file - yes, files are iterable - etc) with `for item in iterable: do_something_with(item)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just one small change to the last line in your for loop

```
match_list_reformat.append(format) if format != '' else False
```

to go through all of your sourcecode change `range(30)` to `range(len(source_code))`

Comment: `else continue` is invalid syntax (at least on 2.7.x and 3.6.x)

Comment: that it is, changed to reflect that

Answer (score 4):

Simplest without `re`,  as Python 3 returns an iterator from filter, so should be wrapped in a call to `list()`

```
>>> mylst
['matchone', '', 'matchtwo', '', 'matchall', '']

>>> list(filter(None, mylst))
['matchone', 'matchtwo', 'matchall']
```

[filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)  is fastest.

**From Documents:**

> filter(function, iterable) Construct an iterator from those elements
>   of iterable for which function returns true. iterable may be either a
>   sequence, a container which supports iteration, or an iterator. If
>   function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all
>   elements of iterable that are false are removed.
>
> Note that filter(function, iterable) is equivalent to the generator
>   expression (item for item in iterable if function(item)) if function
>   is not None and (item for item in iterable if item) if function is
>   None.